# Dynamically adding and removing Views in AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, view

I am using `AsyncTask` to create a `TableLayout` and to remove.
But I am not able to remove it.
the table is adding successfully as needed. But I need to remove all the views when it is called next.

Where am I going wrong?

my code:

```
 private class asyncBrandName extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        if(count==1)
        {
            //((TableLayout)table1.getParent()).removeView(table1);
                container.removeView(table1);
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                    //mycode to create table
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        container=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.container);
        container.addView(table1);
    }
}
```

Comment: maintain instance of `container` properly, declare it in onCreate() and be assure not to initialize again (here in onPostExecute())

Comment: Thanks! Ill do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is nothing other than `table1` in `container`, you can just called `container.removeAllViews()` to clear all child views.  If not, You need to check the following:

1. In `onPreExecute()`, make sure `count == 1` will be `true`.  Maybe `count` is `0`, so that `container.removeView()` does not get called.
2. Is the `contianer` point to the correct layout when you the `asyncTask` is executed? I notice you have set the `container` reference in `onPostExecute()`.
3. Is the `table1` reference changed (Re-created or point to other view) before `asyncTask` is executed?

Comment: Thanks! I have other Views too. And count is 1 in `onPreExecute()`, also I have made the changes with container as suggested by hotveryspicy. table1 refrence is not changed.

Comment: I tried `removeAllViews()` and added all again. It worked but very slow. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: I got it. all I wanted was removeViewAt(index).

Comment: `removeAllViews()` is slow because it is considered expensive to remove/add views to layout, especially if you have many views.
Glad you solve the problem.